# Using anonymous runnable class code goes in deadlock state but with lambda it works fine

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, java-8, anonymous-class

I am trying to find out the cause behind below mentioned code. Here if I create Thread using anonymous inner class it goes into deadlock state but with lambda expressions it works fine. I tried to find the reason behind this behavior but I could not.

```
public class ThreadCreationTest {

    static {
        new ThreadCreationTest();
    }

    private void call() {
        System.out.println("Hello guys!!!");
    }

    public ThreadCreationTest() {

        // when we use this thread it goes in deadlock kind of state
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                call();
            }
        });

        // This one works fine.
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> call());

        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Code finished...");
    }
}
```

**with lambda expression output :**

```
Hello guys!!!
Code finished...
```

**with anonymous class :**

```
code goes into deadlock state
```

Comment: Before anyone else goes down the `java.util.concurrent.Callable` rabbit hole, it still happens even if you rename `call` to `xcall` or similar.

Comment: Really nice puzzler ;) I can give you the hint that removing the private access modificator at the call method will solve the problem but I only have a vague explanation for that.

Answer (score 5):

Decompiling with `javap` the inner class shows the following for the `run` method:

```
public void run();
  descriptor: ()V
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #12                 // Field this$0:Ltest/ThreadCreationTest;
       4: invokestatic  #22                 // Method test/ThreadCreationTest.access$0:(Ltest/ThreadCreationTest;)V
       7: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 31: 0
      line 32: 7
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          0       8     0  this   Ltest/ThreadCreationTest$1;
```

Notice that there is a static synthetic method `access$0` which in turn calls the private method `call`. The synthetic method is created because `call` is private and as far as the JVM is concerned, the inner class is just a different class (compiled as `ThreadCreationTest$1`), which cannot access `call`.

```
static void access$0(test.ThreadCreationTest);
  descriptor: (Ltest/ThreadCreationTest;)V
  flags: ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
  Code:
    stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #68                 // Method call:()V
       4: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 51: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
```

Since the synthetic method is static, it is waiting for the static initializer to finish. However, the static initializer is waiting for the thread to finish, hence causing a deadlock.

On the other hand, the lambda version does not rely on an inner class. The bytecode of the constructor relies on an `invokedynamic` instruction (instruction #9) using `MethodHandles`:

```
public test.ThreadCreationTest();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #13                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: new           #14                 // class java/lang/Thread
         7: dup
         8: aload_0
         9: invokedynamic #19,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:run:(Ltest/ThreadCreationTest;)Ljava/lang/Runnable;
        14: invokespecial #20                 // Method java/lang/Thread."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        17: astore_1
        18: aload_1
        19: invokevirtual #23                 // Method java/lang/Thread.start:()V
        22: aload_1
        23: invokevirtual #26                 // Method java/lang/Thread.join:()V
        26: goto          36
        29: astore_2
        30: invokestatic  #29                 // Method java/lang/Thread.currentThread:()Ljava/lang/Thread;
        33: invokevirtual #33                 // Method java/lang/Thread.interrupt:()V
        36: return
```

Comment: The `invokedynamic` instruction is irrelevant, there will be a synthetic method `lambda$new$0` serving the same purpose as the `access$000` method for the inner class. So the only thing that matters, is, that either is `static` and the other is not. At this point, it’s important to emphasize that it is completely the compiler’s decision whether the synthetic method for a lambda expression will be `static` or not.

Comment: Indeed there is a missing snippet in the bytecode that shows the compiled lambda which I didn't include in this post (shown at the end of the javap output). I don't have access to it at the moment.

Comment: The irony is, that a lambda calling a method on the class under initialization, like `() -> call()`, works, whereas a lambda not calling a method on the class, like `() -> System.out.println()`, doesn’t. Because non-capturing lambda expressions are compiled into synthetic `static` methods…